# MongoDB: Embedded users into comments

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoalchemy, nosql

I cant find "best" solution for very simple problem(or not very)

Have classical set of data: posts that attached to users, comments that attached to post and to user.

Now i can't decide how to build scheme/classes

On way is to store user_id inside comments and inside.
But what happens when i have 200 comments on page?
Or when i have N posts on page?
I mean it should be 200 additional requests to database to display user info(such as name,avatar)

Another solution is to embed user data into each comment and each post.

But first -> it is huge overhead, second -> model system is getting corrupted(using mongoalchemy), third-> user can change his info(like avatar). And what then? As i understand update operation on huge collections of comments or posts is not simple operation...

What would you suggest? Is 200 requests per page to mongodb is OK(must aim for performance)?

Or may be I am just missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the `N+1`-problem of hundreds of requests using [`$in`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-$in)-queries. Consider this:

```
Post {
  PosterId: ObjectId
  Text: string
  Comments: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ...] // option 1
}

Comment {
  PostId: ObjectId // option 2 (better)
  Created: dateTime,
  AuthorName: string,
  AuthorId: ObjectId,
  Text: string
}
```

Now you can find the posts comments with an `$in` query, and you can also easily find all comments made by a specific author.

Of course, you could also store the comments as an embedded array in post, and perform an `$in` query on the user information when you fetch the comments. That way, you don't need to de-normalize user names and still don't need hundreds of queries.

If you choose to denormalize the user names, you will have to update all comments ever made by that user when a user changes e.g. his name. On the other hand, if such operations don't occur very often, it shouldn't be a big deal. Or maybe it's even better to store the name the user had when he made the comment, depending your requirements.

A general problem with embedding is that [different writers will write to the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923440/how-should-the-following-many-to-many-relationship-be-modeled-in-mongodb), so you will have to use the [atomic modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) (such as `$push`). This is sometimes harder to use with mappers (I don't know mongoalchemy though), and generally less flexible.

Comment: Actualy right for now my comments just like this, in separate collection. The only difference, I store post_id inside comment and not array of comments inside post. So when post is read i do additional request to fetch the comments. 
Just a few questions to be sure what you mean:
1) With your schema this one request also should be made(using $in instead of find by post_id)?
2) Do I understand correctly, that you propose to parse array of comments that should be displayed, collect user_id's and then get all users with additional $in request? So total is 3 requests made no matter N of comments?

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify. `Comment` now has a `PostId`, which I think is better. I was afraid your current schema is based on embedding. So 1) no, `$in` is not required, standard query is better. 2) yes, you will have to collect unique user ids from the comments, then fetch those users, then create view models from (comment, user)-pairs. Easy with LINQ / .NET, but might be tricky in other languages. The number of queries is then constant, correct.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do with mongodb would be to embed the user id into the comments (which are part of the structure of the "post" document).

Three simple hints for better performances:

1) Make sure to ensure an index on the user_id

2) Use comment pagination method to avoid querying 200 times the database

3) Caching is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your user objects so you don't have to query the database each time.

I like the idea of embedding user data into each post but then you have to think about what happens when a user's profile is updated? have to make sure that no post is missed.

I would recommend starting out just by skimming how mongo recommends you handle schemas.

> Generally, for "contains" relationships between entities, 
>   embedding should be be chosen. Use linking when not using linking would result in 
>   duplication of data.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

Comment: Thanks, but just after reading this official post i decided on embedding. And now, when project grows, user object getting expanded and already two times encountered the issue, that comment object lacks some of user object(was not pushing all the data, only necessary). Well, it became such a mess. Of course i am aknowledge about ther caching. But thinking about performance I prefer to get the best before caching, and not to use caching as solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good use case from the MongoDB docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/
Conveniently it's also written in Python :-)